# Area of cycloid

Tags: analysis

We want to calculate the area of the cycloid: $x = a(t-\sin t)$, 
$y=a(1-\cos t)$, with $t\in [0,2π]$.

I know that the solution has to do with the Green's Theorem and calculating the surface integral of $-y\,dx$.

My question is: can we calculate the area by the surface integral of $x\,dy$? Will we get the same result?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Green's theorem to compute an area of a region](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253664/using-greens-theorem-to-compute-an-area-of-a-region)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating the area of a parametric curve you should express the area as follows,

$$A=\int y(x)~dx=\int y(t)\dot x(t)~dt$$

In your case we have $\dot x=a(1-\cos t)=y$, therfore

$$
\begin{align}
A
&=a^2\int_0^{2\pi} (1-\cos t)^2 ~dt\\
&=a^2\left( \frac{3 t}{2} - 2 \sin t + \frac14 \sin 2t\right)\biggr|_0^{2\pi}\\
&=3\pi a^2\approx 9.4248a^2
\end{align}
$$